# SQL: Get all records from one table AND a count of records from a second table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, left-join

Say there are two tables:

**TABLE A**

```
messageID / Message                     / More..
1         / This is the first message   / Etc..
2         / This is the second message  / Etc..
3         / This is the third message   / Etc..
```

**TABLE B**

```
commentID / messageID / Comment 
1         / 2         / This is a comment to the second message 
2         / 2         / This is another comment to the second message 
3         / 3         / This is a comment to the third message
```

The tie between the tables is the **messageID** field.

I would like one query that generates results like this, where I pull ALL the fields out of Table A, and a count of the number of comments for each message from Table B, like so:

```
messageID  / Message                    / More...  / CommentCount
1          / This is the first message  / etc...   / 0
2          / This is the second message / etc...   / 2
3          / This is the third message  / etc...   / 1
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT tableA.*, count(commentID) as commentcount 
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID GROUP BY messageID
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas? It seems like it should be possible to do this in one query. I'm using MSSQL. Thanks for any help.

Comment: your query seems correct. Just use `COUNT(tableB.messageID)` and `GROUP BY tableA.messageID`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scalar subquery will work:

```
SELECT tableA.*
    ,(SELECT count(commentID) FROM tableB WHERE tableA.messageID = tableB.messageID) as commentcount 
FROM tableA
```

As usual, there are a lot of ways to skin this cat, with varying performance profiles.

When using a `GROUP BY`, all columns in the output either need to be in the `GROUP BY` or in aggregate functions - even though there is no variation in the other columns within a messageID, they still would need to be in the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CTE for the same.

```
;WITH CTE_MessageCount (MessageId, Count)
AS
(
SELECT MessageId, Count(*) FROM TableB GROUP BY MessageId
) 

SELECT A.*, T.*
FROM tableA A JOIN CTE_MessageCount T ON A.messageID = T.MessageID
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar, this is a good solution as well. I had "GROUP BY" just because I was trying all kinds of different approaches but didn't actually need it.

Comment: You are most welcome ! Common Table Expressions are preferred over Nested SQL as they are more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.msgCount
  FROM tableA a LEFT JOIN 
    ( SELECT messageID, COUNT(1) AS msgCount FROM tableB b GROUP BY messageID) b
        ON a.messageID =  b.messageID
```