# SQL to return num_rows on RIGHT OUTER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysql-num-rows

I am creating a mini forum for a class assignment, and wish to return the number of comments made on a particular topic according to user ID (the page is a "My Topics" page).

SQL is:

```
SELECT *
FROM topic
    LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON topic.user_id = user.user_id
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN comment ON topic.topic_id = comment.topic_id
    INNER JOIN avatar ON user.user_avatar = avatar.avatar_id
WHERE user.user_id=1
```

Where the user ID is returned by the `$_SESSION`, but for the sake of this question I am setting at 1.

My problem is, the SQL query is only returning topics that HAVE comments. I wish to list all topics regardless of whether comments have been made on them, and also be able to return the number of corresponding rows in the comment table. Any suggestions of where I am going wrong with my SQL would be greatly appreciated!

edit: ignore the avatar stuff, that's just an extra query to display the user's avatar (obviously but thought I should mention that)

Comment: Maybe because you're RIGHT OUTER JOINing it?

Comment: Why the left join users to topics instead of inner join if your where clause constraint is on the user id?

Comment: @amaster507, because I want to get all the topics that user has posted...

Comment: G-nugget, thanks for editing for readability. Obviously will take this on board being fairly new to this forum.

Comment: @fluxcapacitor well the left join returns all topics whether they are related to a user or not and the inner join would return only the topics related to a user then you could narrow down with the where. Do you understand the difference between left outer and inner joins?

Comment: Oh, I understood that LEFT OUTER JOIN would return all the corresponding rows in the selected table (in this case topic), narrowed down by the user_id. Guess I still have a ways to go.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
SELECT *
FROM topic
    INNER JOIN user ON topic.user_id = user.user_id
    INNER JOIN avatar ON user.user_avatar = avatar.avatar_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN comment ON topic.topic_id = comment.topic_id
WHERE user.user_id=1
```

Comment: Glad you edited this :)  The left outer join is correct.  I was going to ask why he was INNER joining on a table that he's LEFT joining.

Comment: Thanks have tried that and I do get all the topics regardless of whether a comment had been made. However I am now thinking I actually need to be using COUNT() on the comment table.

Comment: If you change the above left outer join to this?
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select topic_id, count(*) cnt from comment where user_id=1 group by topic_id) as commentcnt ON topic.topic_id = commentcnt.topic_id
...

Comment: Thankyou again Lajos, however the topic_id (second instance) and cnt are returning NULL. Still don't have my head around how COUNT works so not sure why this is.

Comment: I can see this question is related to the post at [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247902/sql-get-all-records-from-one-table-and-a-count-of-records-from-a-second-table). Will keep working on it :)