# SQL Server : outputting duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, unique, distinct

I am using a prebuilt program so I am unable to directly edit the SQL, I can only edit snippets of it. The problem I am having is that the code is printing out the customer code for as many cases that customer has. For example, if a customer has 57 cases, it will print the customer code 57 times instead of just showing it once such as Customer Code 4 Cases 57 etc.

I was reading that you may not be able to use a Unique or Distinct function with the OVER command but I am not sure how else to make the sum work without it. Here is my code:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; 
DECLARE @ShowZeros nVarChar(4000);

SET @ShowZeros  = 'N';

SELECT 
    SUM ([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Alt]) OVER(PARTITION BY [AR_Customers].    [CustomerCode]) AS [Cases]
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Alt
    , SUM([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk]) OVER(PARTITION BY [AR_Customers]. [CustomerCode]) AS [Total Stock]
    , IC_Products.UnitOfMeasure_Stk
    , IC_Products.Description1
    , IC_Products.ProductCode
    , AR_Customers.Name
    , AR_Customers.CustomerCode
FROM 
    ((( DC_Transactions 
INNER JOIN  
    AR_Customers ON DC_Transactions.CustomerKey = AR_Customers.CustomerKey)
INNER JOIN  
    IC_ProductLots ON DC_Transactions.LotKey = IC_ProductLots.LotKey)
INNER JOIN  
    IC_Products ON DC_Transactions.ProductKey = IC_Products.ProductKey)
WHERE 
    (IC_Products.ProductCode = '      515070')  AND 
    ((CASE WHEN @ShowZeros = 'Y' or @ShowZeros = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE
(ISNULL([IC_ProductLots].[Available_Stk],0))
END) > 0)
ORDER BY 
    IC_Products.ProductCode 
    , AR_Customers.CustomerCode 
    , AR_Customers.Name
```

Output should look similar to below:

```
Cases | U/M  | Total Stock | Description | Cust Name  | Cust Code
-----------------------------------------------------------------
57    | CS   | 1779.45     | Food        | Restaurant | 2
4     | CS   | 120         | Dough       | Bakery     | 44
```

Currently it prints out 57 lines for customer code 2 and 4 lines for customer code 44, displaying the same information for each customer code.

Comment: First of all: What records shall your results contain? One record per customer code? But then, what product details to show? Or one record per customer code and product? Or what else? BTW: "I am using a DBMS so I am unable to directly edit the SQL" makes no sense.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the record should contain the number of cases, the unit of measure of the cases (CS), the total stock weight, the unit of measure (lbs), the product description, the name of the customer, and the name of the customer code. For example it should look like what I added to the question above.

Comment: You're doing a one to many join (customer to transactions), yet expecting to only get one instance from the customer table?  Only way to do that would be to put everything in aggregates (MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG, etc.) that references the detail table, and from your last comment, you're looking for the full detail.

Comment: The first thing to answer when selecting data is: "I want one record per ______". You don't give this answer directly, but as you want to see both, the name of the customer and the product description, I gather you want one result record per customer and product. So these are the columns to group by. I'll write an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Get all records from one table AND a count of records from a second table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247902/sql-get-all-records-from-one-table-and-a-count-of-records-from-a-second-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to be more or less what you want. You say you can only partly edit your query, but well, you need the GROUP BY clause to say which records you want (i.e. one record per product and customer), so this is what mainly needs be done. Then you cannot use an OVER clause, as the aggregation group is given by GROUP BY already. I have made more changes for readability. See what edits you can do.

```
select 
    sum(l.available_alt) as cases
  , p.unitofmeasure_alt
  , sum(l.available_stk) as [total stock]
  , p.unitofmeasure_stk
  , p.description1
  , p.productcode
  , c.name
  , c.customercode
from dc_transactions t
inner join ar_customers c on t.customerkey = c.customerkey
inner join ic_productlots l on t.lotkey = l.lotkey
inner join ic_products p on t.productkey = p.productkey
where p.productcode = '      515070' 
and (@showzeros in ('Y', 'YES') or l.available_stk > 0)
group by p.productcode, c.customercode
  , p.unitofmeasure_alt, p.unitofmeasure_stk, p.description1, c.name
order by p.productcode, c.customercode;
```

Comment: The problem with the system we use is that I can not edit a GROUP BY clause directly and I am not able to add it.

Comment: Okay, then you are back where you started. Instead of using a GROUP BY clause with aggregation functions, you use the same aggregations as analytic functions with OVER. And then, yes, use DISTINCT to remove duplicates. This works, as you can see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a180/1.